# How do you add an animated UIImage to Xcode 8's asset catalog?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, animation, uiimage

When I dragged a number of image files (PNGs numbered imgName1, imgName2, imgName3, ..., imgName100) into a new image set in Xcode 8.2 asset catalog, it took only the first one and then lumped the rest below in 'Unassigned' with a warning.

Is there any way for Xcode to recognize the numbering scheme as subsequent frames in the animated image?  So I can call

```
UIImage* animatedImage = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"imgName" duration:1];
```

without creating hundreds of image sets, one for each frame?

Comment: Try it first with `imgName1.png` `imgName2.png` and `imgName3.png`.  Or try adding them one at a time. See what happens. I'm not having any issues with it at all.

Comment: You can not add all your images to one image set, you need to create a separate one for each. Another option may be to use a sprite map. As far as I know both ways require custom code to display all frames animated. Should not be too hard though.